# Does Google Dialogflow have intent recommendation?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, chatbot, dialogflow-cx, conversational-ai, conversational-design

I'm switching from IBM Watson Assistant to Google Dialogflow. In WA there's a feature called intent recommendation, which taps into live instances, detects the topics/intents that users want, and groups them together into new recommended intents. You can also upload utterances in spreadsheets and intent recommendation does the same thing. Does Dialogflow have something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Likely the closest to your needs is the GCP Product called Contact Center AI Insights.  If we look at this documentation page:

https://cloud.google.com/contact-center/insights/docs/topic-modeling-overview

we find that this product has a feature called "Topic Modeling".  This allows us to examine the current and historic conversation transcriptions and, from that:

- Monitoring topic trends to keep your agents updated.
- Supporting agent
  training as new topics are observed.
- Using topics and their
  distribution to help define Dialogflow intents.

You can also deploy your created topic model to infer topics on new conversations, allowing you to continually classify incoming conversations.